# How to print or select specific rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to print only the data that starts with a number from a SQL string column. Right now its printing complete string (see image). I only want row 2 and 4 as it contains the data starting with a number.
Here is the sql code:

```
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @string2 ='DOB;04 Mar 1199;passport;1234567'
DECLARE @SEP CHAR(1) 
SET @SEP=';'
select @string2
SELECT value
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@string2, @sep)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Tom, what platform do you use as that determines which solutions are viable

Answer (score 3):

You can try this query:-

`SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName regexp '^[0-9]+'`

The above is MySQL specific.

You can use the below query on SQL Server:
[image: Example tested on W3schools]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value in the where clause.
So using the SUBSTRING and the ISNUMERIC functions should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the first 2 characters and check if they're `NUMERIC`

```
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @SEP CHAR(1) 

SET @string2 ='DOB;04 Mar 1199;passport;1234567'
SET @SEP=';'

SELECT [value] FROM 
(
    SELECT value
    FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@string2, @sep)
) a
WHERE IsNumeric(left([value],2)) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a query with using [MySQL Regex Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE COLUMN_NAME REGEXP '[0-9]'`